# Why in Wick theorem the expectation values of products of field operators is equal to the sum of expectation values of pairs of operators?

Tags: operators, wick-theorem

As stated in the title, I understand the expectation value of uncontracted operators are zero, and there are only certain type of pairs of operators remaining in the time ordered product of operators. But isn't it very obvious that the expectation of products of operators are not necessarily the same as the products of expectation of operators?

So after omitting the pairs in which annihilation comes before creation operators, the product of the operators can be written as the sum of product of certain ordered operators, as what is written below:

$$T \hat{C}_\alpha(t) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\beta(t_1) \hat{C}_\gamma(t_2)\hat{C^{\dagger}}_\delta(t')\\
=[T\hat{C}_\alpha(t) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\beta(t_1)][T\hat{C}_\gamma(t_2) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\delta(t')]-[T\hat{C}_\alpha(t) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\delta(t')][T\hat{C}_\gamma(t_2) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\beta(t_1)].\tag{1}$$

But I don't understand the expectation of the product of the operators can be written in this way as well:
$${_0<}|T \hat{C}_\alpha(t) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\beta(t_1) \hat{C}_\gamma(t_2)\hat{C^{\dagger}}_\delta(t')|>_0 \\
=[{_0<}|T\hat{C}_\alpha(t) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\beta(t_1)|>_0][{_0<}|T\hat{C}_\gamma(t_2) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\delta(t')|>_0]-[{_0<}|T\hat{C}_\alpha(t) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\delta(t')|>_0][{_0<}|T\hat{C}_\gamma(t_2) \hat{C^{\dagger}}_\beta(t_1)|>_0].\tag{2}$$

The image comes from Many particle physics by G. D. Mahan.

[image: k]

Comment: Comments to the post (v4): OP's eq. (1) is not the standard [Wick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem). OP's eq. (2) follows from the standard Wick theorem.

Comment: you're right, it's not a standard one, but equivalent to it. And some other authors adopted this kind of elaboration by Mahan as well, like http://tiny.cc/bcw7cz. I am more used to Mahan's way, so want to know how to tackle this question from his perspective.